# How to retrieve a value from a JSON using bash?

Tags: bash, json

I have a command in a bash pipeline that returns me a JSON like the follow:

```
$ aws iot get-registration-code
{
    "registrationCode": "abcd635"
}
```

I would to have the value `abcd635` inside a variable `code` that I can use somewhere in the code.

```
//Pseudo code
regCode = aws iot get-registration-code;
code = regCode.registrationCode
do some stuf with the code variable.
```

Is that a way to achieve this without the use of `jq`? I think it is because jq is too much for this simple JSON.

Comment: Do you *really* mean "using bash" - or do you want to use another external program so long as it's not `jq`? if the latter, which programs are allowed? `mlr`, `perl`, ... ?

Comment: if you mean process json file,it's pretty simple.you can use grep and cut commands to get the value then store it in a variable.

Comment: `jq` or `python` are probably the bests ideas for parsing json. But if the json output is for sure as simple as what you wrote in the question, some bash work on string will be enough

Comment: I have a process running in bash. At some point I need to run this command (aws iot get-registration-code) and I receive back the answer in JSON (Not a file). I just need to retrieve the value, store in a variable and send to another process. I tough jq is too much for this simple JSON.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read `man cut`,`man tr` and do something like:

```
regCode="$( aws iot get-registration-code |\
    tr -d '{}' |\
    cut '-d"' -f4 )"

code="${regCode}.registrationCode"
```

Comment: Thanks I just added `tr -d '[:space:]' |\` to remove the space

Comment: and removed .registrationCode since ${regCode} is not an object